# Grails custom flag in command line

Tags: grails

I need to pass a flag into grails so that i can conditionally include a piece of javascript in a gsp.

I do not want to define a new environment to do this. 
The javascript i'm trying to include is for takana (similar to livereload but better), which is a tool that only works on osx, and i dont want other developers on windows machines to get that javascript piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it in the GSP like this

```
<g:if test="${System.properties['os.name'] == 'Mac OS X'}">
    <script src="/path/to/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</g:if>
```

If you only want to include this JS in the dev. environment, change it to

```
<g:if test="${System.properties['os.name'] == 'Mac OS X'}" env="development">
    <script src="/path/to/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</g:if>
```

Comment: cool! thanks. It is not exactly what i asked, but is indeed what i need in this case :)